# Method invocation 'getInt' may produce 'java.lan.NullPointerException'

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am a beginner and i wan to know what is 'java.lan.NullPointerException' and how to fixe this error?

Method invocation 'getInt'  may produc 'java.lan.NullPointerException'

Answer (score 0):

> I am a beginner and i wan to know what is 'java.lan.NullPointerException' and how to fixe this error?

A [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/lang/NullPointerException.html) occurs when you try to use a variable that isn't instantiated. For example, let's say you have a variable called `myVar`, and you want to execute the function `myFunc(...)` on `myVar`, and it, for some reason, gives you a NullPointerException. The reason this happens is that you haven't created an object ([instantiated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)) it. You need to do `myVar = new MyClass()` before you can use it. Examine the following code:

```
MyClass myVar;          // Defines a MyClass variable called myVar.
myVar = new MyClass();  // Creates an instance of MyClass and assigns it to myVar.
myVar.myFunc();         // Now you can execute myFunc() on myVar.
```

Please read another post explaining NullPointerExceptions before creating your own, as duplicates aren't allowed on StackOverflow. Also, please consult [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when creating future questions, as well as when editing your old posts.

Also, keep in mind that this post is a duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Finally, as for this:

> Method invocation 'getInt' may produc 'java.lan.NullPointerException'

You need to explain where you're getting this `getInt()` function.

For now, my recommendation is you remove the "what is a NullPointerException", and expand the `getInt()` stuff, try showing us your code!

Also, if my question answered your question, please mark as answered.